# How to move from page refresh to dynamic in django

Tags: django, ajax, rest

My Django website currently runs everything through page refresh. If i click on an upvote button, it updates the model and refreshes the page to show the question as voted up.

What is the best way to move from this page refresh to a more dynamic in-page refresh?

I have heard i should be using Ajax and Django rest framework. Is there a difference between this method and using something like React?

Comment: The best solution is obviously serializing your data with drf and using React components to display them dynamically, you can use ajax as well but it's not that common anymore, React is your best bet

Comment: what do you mean by drf?

Comment: DRF = Django Rest Framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/